# Angular - hide/show column in a table when checkbox is selected

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I'm trying to hide whole column with all elements in that column when the checkbox is clicked. I'm wondering what's the best approach to solve that using Angular.

```
 <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Name</th>
                        <th scope="col">Email</th>
                        <th scope="col">Date</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr *ngFor="let user of Items" >
                        <td>{{user.Name}}</td>
                        <td>{{user.Email}}</td>
                        <td>{{user.Date}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Above the table I have 3 checkboxes:

Name | Email | Date

I want to press one of them and then whole column disappears including `<th>` element and `<td>` element. 
What could be the best idea for this problem?

Comment: Are you asking about column?

Comment: Of course, my fault, column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To hide columns when a checkbox is selected.

In your .ts create 3 variables set to true for each column.

```
showName = true;
showEmail = true;
showDate = true;
```

in your respective checkboxes you need to add checked and change calls for each and match it to the 3 booleans above:

```
  <input type="checkbox" [checked]="!showName" (change)="showName=!showName"/>

  <input type="checkbox" [checked]="!showEmail" (change)="showEmail=!showEmail"/>

  <input type="checkbox" [checked]="!showDate " (change)="showDate =!showDate "/>
```

And then add *ngIf in each related th and td for example for the name td and th:

```
<th scope="col" *ngIf="showName">Name</th>
<td *ngIf="showName">{{user.Name}}</td>
```

Answer (score 2):

declare class

```
  export class ColumnVisible{
       public nameVisible:boolean=true;
       public emailVisible:boolean=true;
       public dateVisible:boolean=true;
       constructor(){}
    }
```

call it in component

```
columnVisible:ColumnVisible;
```

in costructor initialize it with

```
this.columnVisible=new ColumnVisible();
```

inhtml write as class and give click event

```
<input [(ngModel)]="columnVisible.nameVisible" type="checkbox"(change)="columnVisible.nameVisible=!columnVisible.nameVisible" /> 
<input [(ngModel)]="columnVisible.emailVisible" type="checkbox"(change)="columnVisible.emailVisible=!columnVisible.emailVisible" /> 
<input [(ngModel)]="columnVisible.dateVisible" type="checkbox"(change)="columnVisible.dateVisible=!columnVisible.dateVisible" /> 
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th  ngIf="columnVisible.nameVisible" scope="col">Name</th>
            <th  ngIf="columnVisible.emailVisible" scope="col">Email</th>
            <th  ngIf="columnVisible.dateVisible" scope="col">Date</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let user of Items" class="{{user.IsShown}}" >
            <td ngIf="columnVisible.nameVisible" >{{user.Name}}</td>
            <td ngIf="columnVisible.emailVisible">{{user.Email}}</td>
            <td ngIf="columnVisible.dateVisible">{{user.Date}}</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little bit of code. [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x77gcu). You just need three different models for different checkboxes or use 1 property but with different types